# Python script closes without even running

Tags: python

I wrote a python script to run some simple tasks and this issue has been happening randomly at times.
Upon clicking on .py file, a cmd prompt window appears for a some microseconds and closes immediately without showing any text.
I thought this issue was because the code finished running too fast at first but the code doesnt actually run. I know this because the code involves sending a text message on discord through the requests module and I can see post-running that no text has been sent.
If it was the prior assumed issue, I would've just added some input for the program to recieve but my program has an infinite while loop in it which should be already enough to keep the cmd window open. Hence I dont understand what's causing this.

The last time it happened I somehow found a solution which I followed step by step and was able to resolve it but its happening again now and I cant find that solution again unfortunately. From vague memory, I recall the solution involved running some commands on windows terminal.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: pls add your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you double clicking the .py file? If so, it may not work in some situations. What you should do is open up your cmd and type the following.

`C:\Users\Admin> python filename.py`

You can replace `filename` with your file's name.
If you are using Mac or any Apple devices, you will need to replace `python` with `python3`.